# Facebook feed with windows app

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-8, facebook-c#-sdk, windows

I would like to take the facebook feed from a facebook page and add display it (the statuses and images) on my windows store app. I have installed the Facebook SDK for .NET and I am trying to find some tutorials but all I can find is how to add a login screen. Any ideas what I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are new to C# SDK, you can start from here: [Facebook SDK for .NET](http://facebooksdk.net/docs/windows/)

**Concept**

You can get the feeds from a page using:

```
/PAGE_ID/feed
```

You can get the photos from a page using:

```
/PAGE_ID/photos
```

(only if the feeds/photos are public)

**Implementation**

Example-

```
FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient(App.AccessToken);

dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
parameters.access_token = App.AccessToken;

dynamic result = await fb.GetTaskAsync("PAGE_ID/feed", parameters);
```

**Graph API Explorer Examples**-

You can get the parameters you required.

[Posts Example](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=Shadowfax.sahil%2Ffeed%3Ffields%3Dmessage)

[Photos example](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=Shadowfax.sahil%2Fphotos%3Ffields%3Dsource)

Comment: How do I integrate this with the xaml viewer though? As in how do I display the feed on the app?

Comment: You can bind the result with your view. And pls accept the ans if the solution worked for you.

Comment: Since it is a Json object how do I bind it to my view?

Comment: You can do it in any way you like to. For eg: define the required properties in your viewmodel; and assign the values from the json to these properties and then bind. If you still have difficulties, you can post ques with the data so that we can help.

Comment: Is there somewhere I can see what values/items are being obtained from the json? I want to display the page statuses and images